# Извлечь подстроку из строк в python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, подстрока

Как из текста с рейтингом фильмов извлечь подстроку содержащую рейтинг и название фильма ([`'9.2  The Shawshank Redemption'], ['9.2  The Godfather'],...`.

```
    note: for this top 250, only votes from regular voters are considered.

New  Distribution  Votes  Rank  Title
      0000000125  1888533   9.2  The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
      0000000125  1289428   9.2  The Godfather (1972)
      0000000124  889607   9.0  The Godfather: Part II (1974)
      0000000124  1864164   9.0  The Dark Knight (2008)
      0000000133  518449   8.9  12 Angry Men (1957)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

a='''
    note: for this top 250, only votes from regular voters are considered.

New  Distribution  Votes  Rank  Title
      0000000125  1888533   9.2  The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
      0000000125  1289428   9.2  The Godfather (1972)
      0000000124  889607   9.0  The Godfather: Part II (1974)
      0000000124  1864164   9.0  The Dark Knight (2008)
      0000000133  518449   8.9  12 Angry Men (1957)
      '''

res = re.findall(r"(\d+\.\d+\s+.+)\s\(", a)
```

res:

```
['9.2  The Shawshank Redemption',
 '9.2  The Godfather',
 '9.0  The Godfather: Part II',
 '9.0  The Dark Knight',
 '8.9  12 Angry Men']
```

Answer (score 1):

Тестировать регулярные выражения можно здесь https://regex101.com

Матчасть https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/

Решение:

```
import re

text = '''note: for this top 250, only votes from regular voters are considered.

New  Distribution  Votes  Rank  Title
      0000000125  1888533   9.2  The Shawshank Redemption (1994)
      0000000125  1289428   9.2  The Godfather (1972)
      0000000124  889607   9.0  The Godfather: Part II (1974)
      0000000124  1864164   9.0  The Dark Knight (2008)
      0000000133  518449   8.9  12 Angry Men (1957)'''

rank_title = re.compile(r'\s{3}(\d+\.\d+\s\s?.+).+\(\d+\)$', re.MULTILINE)
print([list(i.groups()) for i in rank_title.finditer(text)])
```